# What is the reason for different learned features in upper and lower half in AlexNet?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, alexnet

I was reading AlexNet paper and the authors quoted

> the kernels on one GPU were "largely color agnostic," whereas the kernels on the other GPU were largely "color-specific."

The upper GPU takes operates on filters on the top and lower GPU deals with the lower half. But what is the reason for each of them learning a different set of features, i.e. the top half of kernels learning the edges mostly and the bottom kernels learning color variation? Is there any reason behind it?

[image: alexnet-kernels]